# personalize fb login button with image

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want to personalize connect with facebook button with custom image:
if i use the traditional facebook custom button, everything seems working right, but if i change it seems not working at all
here the original:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

wthat i have tried:

```
<img src="img/fb_login.png" onclick="FB.login()" />
```

but seems not working, some advice?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="loginBtn">Facebook Login</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile'});
}, false);
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Of course you have to load the JavaScript SDK first.